# How to 'gradle build'?

Tags: java, gradle, httpclient

Could not find method application() for arguments

i tried gradle build but got this error

then i want to build the OneDrive client

i do not want to GET making a returnurl or get it by other means.

```
plugins {
    id 'application'

}

 application {
   mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.app.App'

}

 apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceSets {
      main {
        java {
        srcDir 'src'
     }
 }


dependencies {
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.10'
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.12'
   compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', 
   version: '4.5.10'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', 
 version: '4.4.12'

}


repositories {
    jcenter()
   maven {
    url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient"
}
maven {
    url
```

Comment: What Gradle version are you using?

Comment: Call `gradlew` to use the Gradle wrapper that prevents version problems.

Comment: is the build.gradle file truncated? the lase `maven{` block is never closed. What gradle version are you using? (check that with `gradle --version`)